# Getting error 403 (forbidden) on local server, when trying to add a image dynamically to a html page

Tags: javascript, php, image, xampp, src

I have around 20 images and instead adding them manually to the HTML page I want to add them dynamically via JAVASCRIPT. I get the image path from a json file. So far so good.

See in the example below how I add the image and where I get the error message:
"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)"

```
var image = document.createElement("img");
image.src = 'path/to/my/image.jpg;
...
..
element.appendChild(image);
```

But when I simply change background images via jquery everything works fine:

```
$(#element).css("background", 'path/to/my/image.jpg)
```

SPECS: 
running XAMPP 1.8.3 with Apache and php 5.5.6 on Windows 7 x64

Any solutions?

Thank you in Advance.

//SOLVED: The image path was wrong.

Comment: Right click on the image, copy image location and paste it here please.

Comment: Have you tried accessing the image directly as returned by the JSON document? What are the exact permissions on the directory, does the web server have read access on it and/or the images?

Comment: Thank you for the fast response. I found the problem. The image path was wrong... sorry for wasting your time ...

But do you think the way I create the images is OK for a small website? Or should I rather go for a database solution (mySQL etc.)?